# File attribute to prevent purging of data in iOS 5.0.1?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, icloud

WIth iOS 5.0.1 the new file attribute to prevent data from being backed up has been introduced but I remember that  I read somewhere that there is also a new flag that can be set to prevent data form being purged in low memory situations. Does anybody know?

I know this article here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011342 
But it is dealing with backup flags only and states that files that should not be purged should be placed in the document's folder. I know all that but I'm looking specifically for a way to prevent data from being purged that is NOT in the documents folder.

Comment: there's a post here which goes into what you're asking about.. http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning

unfortunately, as far as i know, the general consensus is that yes, it's a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store your data in `<Application_Home>/Library/Private Documents`, as stated in that article. It won't get purged from there, and you can then set the do-not-backup flag.

Comment: I got that. But it does not really answer the question. What about this mysterious flag that is supposed to prevent purging?

Comment: `<Application_Home>/Library/Private Documents` never gets purged. There's no flag for purging AFAIK, its specific to some directories (like `Library/Caches`).

Comment: Okay, multiple people confirmed: there is no flag to prevent purging. Must have been wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for these methods in MonoTouch.Foundation.NSFileManager:

```
public static bool GetSkipBackupAttribute (string filename);
public static bool GetSkipBackupAttribute (string filename, out NSError error);
public static NSError SetSkipBackupAttribute (string filename, bool skipBackup);
```